# Insert characters only if a column has n characters in AWK

Tags: awk

This is my file:

```
DI3456###numeric###Closed###RPVFF123###13:00:23###no
DI4321###numeric###Open###RPVFG345###1 10:00:15###yes
DI9876###numeric###Closed###RPVGG678###09:15:16###no
DI6788###numeric###Closed###RPHH123###5 05:05:00##yes
```

I am trying to insert a zero and a space in column 5 only if the field has 8 characters like this:

```
"13:00:23"     "0 13:00:23" 

"09:15:16"     "0 09:15:16"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Try `cat file.txt | sed "s/###\([0-9][0-9]:\)/###0 \1/"`

Comment: What is your desired output for the input that you have shown?

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="###"} length($5)==8 {$5="0 "$5}1' myfile

DI3456###numeric###Closed###RPVFF123###0 13:00:23###no
DI4321###numeric###Open###RPVFG345###1 10:00:15###yes
DI9876###numeric###Closed###RPVGG678###0 09:15:16###no
DI6788###numeric###Closed###RPHH123###5 05:05:00##yes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '-F###' '{if (length($5)==8){$5="0 "$5};print $0}'
```

Comment: Small typo setting the field separator --- the `F` needs to be uppercase (`-F###`). Also I think you'll lose the separator on output if you don't also set `OFS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(#{3})([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}#{3}(no|yes))$/\10 \2/' file.txt
```

Should make it. This slightly simpler one should also work but it is less strict on the time pattern:

```
sed -r 's/(#{3})([0-9:]{8}#{3}(no|yes))$/\10 \2/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
DI3456###numeric###Closed###RPVFF123###13:00:23###no
DI4321###numeric###Open###RPVFG345###1 10:00:15###yes
DI9876###numeric###Closed###RPVGG678###09:15:16###no
DI6788###numeric###Closed###RPHH123###5 05:05:00##yes
```

You can use Perl:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne '@a=split(/#+/); print "\"$a[4]\"\t\"0 $a[4]\"" if length($a[4])==8'
"13:00:23"  "0 13:00:23"
"09:15:16"  "0 09:15:16"
```